# How can I use my local file from Internal Storage as AssetFileDescriptor?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-contentprovider, android-assets

My Class is extending *android.content*.**ContentProvider** and overrides *public final AssetFileDescriptor* **openAssetFile()** method from it.

> ```
> public class MyContentProvider extends ContentProvider {
>      @Override
>      public boolean onCreate() {
>          //Some code
>      }
>
>      @Nullable
>      @Override
>      public AssetFileDescriptor openAssetFile(@NonNull Uri uri, @NonNull String mode) {
>
>          final int matchCode = MATCHER.match(uri);
>          if (matchCode == SOME_ASSET_CODE || matchCode == STICKER_PACK_TRAY_ICON_CODE) {
>              return getImageAsset(uri);
>          }
>          return null;
>      }
>
>
>      private AssetFileDescriptor getImageAsset(Uri uri) throws IllegalArgumentException {
>          AssetManager am = Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()).getAssets();
>          try {
>              return am.openFd(identifier + "/" + fileName);
>          } catch (IOException e) { 
>              return null;
>          }
>      }
>  }
> ```

I want to download files from my server and use them for my content.
I have tried casting the file object to an AssetFileDescriptor like this:

> ```
> public class MyContentProvider extends ContentProvider {
>      private AssetFileDescriptor getImageAsset(Uri uri) throws IllegalArgumentException {
>          AssetFileDescriptor contentsJsonFileAsset = (AssetFileDescriptor) myContentFile;
>          try {
>              File myAssetFile = new File(identifier + "/" + fileName);
>              AssetFileDescriptor contentsJsonFileAsset = (AssetFileDescriptor) myContentFile;
>              return contentsJsonFileAsset ;
>          } catch (IOException e) { 
>              return null;
>          }
>      }
>  }
> ```

But it gives following error:

> ```
> Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'java.io.File' to 'android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor'
> ```

**Is there any way to achieve this? Or can I use something else instead of ContentProvider?**

Comment: You cannot cast random types to other random types and expect that to work. To create an instance of `AssetFileDescriptor`, you can use its constructor. That takes a `ParcelFileDescriptor`, and you can get one of those for your `File` using [the `open()` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ParcelFileDescriptor#open(java.io.File,%20int)).

Comment: This helped me a lot. It worked as expected. Thanks!

Comment: Can anyone of you please post example code you did or implying will work...

Answer (score 0):

Following up on the answer from @CommonsWare, this is what you can use to create an `AssetFileDescriptor` from a `File`:

```
AssetFileDescriptor contentsJsonFileAsset = new AssetFileDescriptor(ParcelFileDescriptor.open(myAssetFile, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY), 0L, myAssetFile.length());
```